# Why is the space of nilpotent spaces of matrices Zariski closed?

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, nilpotence

I'm reading the paper ["Nilpotent subspaces of maximal dimension in semi-simple Lie algebras"](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2218906) by Jan Draisma, Hanspeter Kraft, and Jochen Kuttler.  The authors are generalizing a [theorem of Gerstenhaber](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0096678) on the maximal dimension of a vector space of nilpotent matrices to a Lie algebra setting.

I'm stuck on a detail at the start of Section 2.  They're looking at the nilpotent cone $\mathcal{N}_\mathfrak{g}$, consisting of all nilpotent Lie elements.  This is well-known to be Zariski closed.  (In the motivating case from Gerstenhaber where the Lie algebra is the matrix algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, I guess you can see this by setting the traces of powers to 0, since these are polynomial in the entries of the matrix.)  I think I understand what they're saying, thus far.

They then go on to say that:

> The space $Z_m := \{V \in \operatorname{Gr}_m(\mathfrak{g}) : V \subseteq \mathcal{N}_\mathfrak{g}\}$
>   is clearly Zariski closed in $\operatorname{Gr}_m$.

Here, $\operatorname{Gr}_m$ is the [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian), consisting of all vector subspaces of $\mathfrak{g}$ having dimension $m$.

Why is the statement about $Z_m$ clear?  Is there an elementary explanation, at least in the matrix case?  (And what is the 'right' explanation for someone that really knows algebraic geometry?)

Comment: I don't know all of the notation you are using, but $A\in\mathrm{Mat}_m(F)$ is nilpotent if and only if $A^m=0$. This equation can be expressed as $m^2$ polynomial equations in the entries of $A$ which means that it's a subvariety of $\mathrm{Mat}_m(F)$.

Comment: @Alex, yes, that's what I'm saying around the nipotent cone, possibly confusingly.  The paper I'm looking at is written in terms of Lie algebras; the matrix case is a nice concrete and accessible example.

Comment: If you choose an embedding of $G$ into $\mathrm{GL}_n$ then isn't the 'nilpotent cone' the pullback of the nilpotent cone for $\mathrm{GL}_n$? Thus, doesn't it reduce to the $\mathrm{GL}_n$ case (since preimage of closed is closed)? Perhaps I'm not understanding. This should also work for Lie algebras I suspect (using Ado's theorem).

Comment: Yeah, the nilpotent cone part is fairly clear.  I wasn't seeing how to translate Zariski closedness to the Grassmannian.  Edited to hopefully clarify what I'm asking, and what Lazzaro answered below.

Comment: My bad, I just completely didn't read your question fully. Sorry about that! Glad it got answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of the following lemma, which doesn't have anything to do with matrices. A reference is Section 6.1.1 of Eisenbud--Harris, *3264 And All That*. (I am writing it in the projective setting, but you can projectivise everything in sight in your question to convert it to this form.)

**Lemma:** Let $X \subset \mathbf P^n$ be a Zariski-closed set. Let $\mathbf G(k,n)$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbf P^n$. Define

$$ F_k(X) := \left\{ V \in \mathbf G(k,n) \mid V  \subset X \right\}. $$

Then $F_k(X)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbf G(k,n)$.

You should look at Eisenbud--Harris for an idea of how to prove it. The basic idea is that $X$ is cut out by homogeneous polynomials $F_1,\ldots,F_n$ of degrees $d_1,\ldots,d_n$. Each of these defines a certain section $\varphi_i$ of a certain vector bundle $\Sigma_i$ on the Grassmannian, and $F_k(X)$ is exactly the common zero locus of the sections $\varphi_i$.

The set $F_k(X)$ is traditionally called the *Fano variety* or *Fano scheme* of $k$-planes on $X$.

Comment: Thank you!  I thought that there ought to be a result of that form, but am not familiar enough with the algebraic geometry literature to find it!  Off to look in Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: Similar material seems to be in Example 6.19 of Harris's _Algebraic geometry: a first course_.  It's in the language of varieties there, rather than the scheme language of Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: do you happen to know a reference for the analogous result for products of Grassmannians?  That is, assuming I'm not mistaken, it looks like the same techniques can be used to show that if X is closed in P^m \times P^n, then the subset of all {V \times W in G(k,n) \times G(j,n) with every (v,w) in X} is closed.  But I'm surprised not to find it in the literature!

Comment: Dear Russ, I don't know a reference for what you ask. As you say, it seems to follow in more or less the same way as the original claim.